# error in migrations/0001_initial.py when upgrading to DJango 2: migrations/0001_initial.py

Tags: django, upgrade, django-migrations

I've recently upgraded from Django 1.11 to 2.1

This went fine in two different test envorinments, but when I tried to apply the changes to my productions environment, I get an error when I try to makemigrations:

```
$ ./src/manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./src/manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  ...
  File "/home/90158/hackerspace/src/quest_manager/migrations/0001_initial.py", line 69, in Migration
    ('quest', models.ForeignKey(to='quest_manager.Quest')),
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

Of course, many of the changes I needed to make were to add `on_delete` to my ForeignKeys, but none of my test environments gave this migration error!

EDIT:

When I run `python -Wa src/manage.py test` in my test environment I don't get any warnings or errors.  It also migrates no problem in my test environment.

Comment: Why are you running `makemigrations` in production? You should do that locally while making changes, then merge to dev/staging & then merge to production. Can you add the model to your question?

Comment: That sounds like it's beyond my current amatuer ability.  Can you recommend a resource for me to learn about this workflow?

Comment: It sounds like you need to have a look at git & implement some version control; https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Answer (score 0):

Just add where your `ForeignKey` is;

```
models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You can take a look at this for more options. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#arguments

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have already added on_delete to all my foreign keys in the models themselves. The problem is that this error is appearing in the initial migration 0001_initial.py and I don't understand why.  That migration would have been made with django < 2.